# Create scss file using NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I'd like to generate a .scss file using NodeJS and "fs.writeFile" but it doesn't work, and I don't know what is the best way to do it.

**My js code  (path = '/sass/bottom/_settings.scss' ):**

```
BottomGenerator.prototype.createSettings = function(path, color, columnWidth){

    var _settings = "
        @import \"compass/css3\";
        @import \"compass/typography\";
        @import \"compass/css3/transition\";
        @import \"compass/css3/transform\";
        @import \"compass/css3/text-shadow\";
        @import \"compass/css3/box-shadow\";
        @import \"compass/css3/user-interface\";
        @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600);
        $total-columns      : 12;
        $column-width       : "+columnWidth+"px;
        $gutter-width       : 10px;
        $container-width    : ( $total-columns * $column-width) + ( $total-columns * $gutter-width ) - 10;
        $color              : "+color+";
        $gray               : lighten(#000000, 10%);
    ";

    fs.writeFile(path, _settings, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });

}
```

**Edit 1 (issue found):**

```
    var str = fs.readFileSync(lib+'/_settings.ejs', 'utf8');

BottomGenerator.prototype.createSettings = function(path, color, columnWidth){

    var _settings = ejs.render(str, {
        color: color,
        columnWidth: columnWidth
    });

    fs.writeFile(path, _settings, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });

}
```

And an ejs file (_settings.ejs):

```
    @import "compass/css3";
    @import "compass/typography";
    @import "compass/css3/transition";
    @import "compass/css3/transform";
    @import "compass/css3/text-shadow";
    @import "compass/css3/box-shadow";
    @import "compass/css3/user-interface";
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600);

    $total-columns      : 12;
    $column-width       : <%= columnWidth %>px;
    $gutter-width       : 10px;
    $container-width    : ( $total-columns * $column-width) + ( $total-columns * $gutter-width ) - 10;
    $color              : <%= color %>;
    $gray               : lighten(#000000, 10%);
```

Comment: this runs? Node.js is a JavaScript interpreter, I'm pretty sure you need to either do individual concatenations, or you need to indicate this is a multiline string by using \\ at the end of each line.

Comment: I found a solution and it works !

Comment: nice! finding the solution before someone answers your questions' always cool. although it's probably worth removing this question then.